# Any android event when keyboard slide out

Tags: android

Is there any intent/event that i can listen to when user slide out the keyboard on a phone with keyboard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your Manifest file, add this to your activity definition:
`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"`

and in your Activity java file, override the method `onConfigurationChanged`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
       //handle keyboard slide out event
    }
    else if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES)
        //handle keyboard slide in event
    }
}
```

when a keyboard event fires off in this activity, this method will be called and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. On android emulator, how can I emulate keyboard sliding in /out?

Comment: Works only with hardware keyboard

Answer (score 2):

There is an `ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` broadcast you can listen to. The solutions provided by @schwiz and @binnyb have a major flaw -- they force you to deal with all of the actual work of the configuration change. That may be necessary, but you are far better served not overriding `android:configChanges`, and using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` for handling the actual configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in your Activity override `onConfigurationChanged()`

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
   if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO){
       //slideout detected
   }
}
```