# Android hide keyboard on backkeypressed

Tags: android, android-layout, events

I have successfully made part of my layout dissapear using

```
    activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);    
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
           System.out.println("Height: "+heightDiff);

            if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...

            RelativeLayout bottom = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);
            bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else {

                RelativeLayout bottom = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);
                bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: Isen't the keyboard hidden by the android system on back button pressed ? Anyway, you have to override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)

Comment: yes but i want bottom_layout to be visible again when the keyboard is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way more proper to detect when the keyboard appeard and is hidden :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int actualHeight = getHeight();

    if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
        // Keyboard is shown
    } else {
        // Keyboard is hidden
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

source : [Any android event when keyboard slide out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046748/any-android-event-when-keyboard-slide-out)

Comment: ok i added  @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
 {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
             // Your code to show bottom_layout
     RelativeLayout bottom = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);
        bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 }
  but no result

Comment: okie i have done this  @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
 {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); no result

             if (newConfig.keyboard == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) 
             {
              bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             } else {
              bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
 }

Comment: i post my manifest in updated question deficollectif is where i put your config change

Answer (score 2):

try to this one

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
           button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: yes but how can i make bottom_layout visible when onbackpressed is pressed

Comment: i did  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
      
        RelativeLayout bottom = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);
        bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 
 }
  but no result

Comment: because there in no widget only layout. try to add button or textview in Relative layout and use the visibility

Comment: i have a button and an imageview in my relative layout

Comment: try to visible to image view and button here

Comment: i tried your code but still the button and image remains invisible