# how to display Toast on Keyborad on / off in android

Tags: android, keyboard

Below is my code i am trying to display toast message on Keyboard on and off on device, my code running but i am unable to display toast message please tell me where is the issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.keyboard.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

below is manifest file code so please tell me where am doing wrong i am unable to display toast  when i enable and disable keyboard.

Comment: in your `Manifest` file, add this to your activity definition: `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"` and then try..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any android event when keyboard slide out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046748/any-android-event-when-keyboard-slide-out)

Comment: have you tried putting debug points at your `toast`? Because I think it might not getting there..

Comment: yes but its not working when open and off Key ..

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
<application  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden" ... />
```

in your manifest.xml file

**Edit:**
From here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365637/3117296) i figured it out that this solution will not work for **soft keyboard** :(

Comment: still not working i just want to fire one event on keyboard on and off

Comment: Well! What do you want to do when the keyboard state changed ?

Comment: yes i just want display toast when keyboard on or off

Comment: It is not possible using soft keyboard see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android/4365637#4365637)

Comment: yaar u just try in ur device and check is it working

Comment: Simply you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the keyboard hidden you can use this in your Android Manifest XML file.

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

And if you want to hide the keyboard on touch outside the soft keyboard area you can use this in your java class.

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And you can try this link to detect the on/off of the soft keyboard.
ref:http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1758842/

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: i have to toast  press on key board open and disable message in toast if keyboard off

Comment: i am trying but am not getting any event on press key or keyboard on

Comment: The code you've been using only works for the HARD KEYBOARD not the soft keyboard .
The post has been answered in this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/howto-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android

Comment: please tell me for softkeyboard

Answer (score 0):

You are checking hard keyboard state, which is the state of a real physical keyboard if it's present. You should check [any keyboard state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboardHidden):

```
if (newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if (newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: hey i have use same code but still same issue am facing still toast is not displaying on Key open and off